# bottom aligning - responsive layout

Tags: css

I have this problem with an aligning issue. I am building this responsive site using twitter bootstrap and my client wants me to align bottom some content from two different spans lik this:

[image]

He wants the grey box on the right in the right span4 to align bottom with the flexSlider on the left in the other span4. How can this be achieved? i cant use margin on the right side since the upper content is dynamic and can be much longer. i have tried using a relative positioned wrapper and absolutely positioned it but thet width of the grey box and everything gets all messed up when trying to resize the browser window to a smaller size..Any other way to go besides absolute positioning?

Here is the markup:

```
               <div class="span8">
                    <div class="row section professionIntro">
                        <div class="span4">
                            <div class="flexslider section">
                                  <ul class="slides">
                                    <li>
                                      <img src="img/slide1.png" alt="slide 1" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                      <img src="img/slide2.png" alt="slide 2" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                      <img src="img/slide3.png" alt="slide 3" />
                                    </li>
                                  </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span4">
                            <p class="intro">Som dataingeniør jobber du med systemutvikling og drift av maskiner eller systemer.</p>
                            <ul class="infoExpand">
                                <li class="expandVideo">
                                    <h2 class="videoSign">Video dataingeniøren hverdag</h2>   
                               </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
```

Appreciate any help..

Comment: Is it possible to see the CSS that you are using in relation to the markup?

Comment: I would make `.span8` `position:relative` and `.infoExpand` `position: absolute; left:0; bottom:0;`. Then give it a width as a percentage (`width: 50%`). That way it should scale properly. You might need to play with those values but...

Comment: using left:0 wont work, that will just put the infoExpand over the flexSlider since the span8 wraps them both

Answer (score 0):

Add css responsive:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
```

If is button position:absolute is converting position:static;

```
.videoSign {
    position : static;
    bottom:auto;
    top:auto;
    left:auto;
    right:auto;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/sEryj/